# Change repository name in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

Does anyone know how to set/change a repository name in alfresco?

```
id=-default-, name=, description=, capabilities=Repository Capabilities
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this output? And what does the repository console say about the name of your repo? (The one at `/alfresco/s/enterprise/admin/admin-systemsummary` )

Comment: I'm using Apache Chemistry to get this information with the getRepositories() method from SessionFactory class. And I'm using Alfresco Community so that link is giving me "Web Script Status 404 - Not Found" even if I try `/alfresco/s/community/admin/admin-syste‌​msummary`

Answer (score 2):

The Alfresco CMIS calls started returning an empty string for name sometime around 5.0, I believe. According to the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/os/CMIS-v1.1-errata01-os-complete.html#x1-210003), the name is not a required piece of information. The server is required to return a unique ID for each repository in the system, but that's it.

I do not believe you can change the name without touching Alfresco CMIS implementation Java classes.

Besides, Alfresco only supports a single repository so a name isn't going to add a lot of value.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! It was a lot of help. But yeah, I needed the name to integrate it to IBM BPM. At last I changed to Alfresco 4.2 since there I have the name of the repository.